# Why is a delay needed for reading Rx SPI register correctly?

Tags: c, delay, spi

I'm using the uC CH32V003 and module MAX6675 for reading temperature. According to the MAX6675's datasheet the maximum time conversion is 220ms, for this I  have configured the TIMER1 to get an interruption each 240ms.
The code for reading the temperature using SPI is placed in main() and also using the function read_temperature(). However, the code in main() and in read_temperature() only work if I add a delay after reading the Rx SPI register.

```
temperature = SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI1);
Delay_Ms(2);
```

If I use the function read_temperature() and no delay is added I got only 0.0, with a delay of 5ms I got -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0 and so on, with a delay of 8ms I got 0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 20.75, 20.50, 21.0, 20.50 (that's more or less correct). However, in debugging mode everything works well, it is not necessary any  delay after reading Rx SPI register

If I add the code for rotary encoder, I have to increase the delay to 20ms to make it works well.

I am missing something?

Datasheet MAX6675 [here](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX6675.pdf)

Code below:

```
#include "debug.h"

#define PSC_1ms SystemCoreClock/1000

uint8_t i=0;

/* Temperature variables */
volatile uint8_t read_temp_flag = 0;
volatile float val; // temperature
uint16_t val_int = 0;
uint16_t val_decimal = 0;
volatile uint16_t temperature;

/* temporary variables */
uint32_t tmp = 0;
uint32_t tmp2 = 0;

void TIM1_UP_IRQHandler(void)__attribute__((interrupt("WCH-Interrupt-fast")));
void TIM1_CC_IRQHandler(void)__attribute__((interrupt("WCH-Interrupt-fast")));
float read_temperature(void);
void Systick_Init(void);
void float_printf(float);

void TIM1_UP_IRQHandler(void){
    if(TIM_GetITStatus(TIM1, TIM_IT_Update) != RESET){
        GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_2);
        read_temp_flag = 1;
        //printf("UP : %d\r\b",TIM1->CNT);
        TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM1, TIM_IT_Update);
    }
}

void TIM1_CC_IRQHandler(void){
    if(TIM_GetITStatus(TIM1, TIM_IT_CC1)!=RESET){
        //GPIO_WriteBit(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_2, (i == 0) ? (i = Bit_SET) : (i = Bit_RESET));
        GPIO_SetBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_2);
        //printf("CC1 %d\r\n",TIM1->CNT);
        TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM1, TIM_IT_CC1);
    }
}

/*
 * MISO -> C.7
 * SCK -> C.5
 * CS -> C.0
 */

void SPI1_Init(void){

    SPI_InitTypeDef SPI_InitStructure = {0};
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure = {0};

    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOC | RCC_APB2Periph_SPI1, ENABLE);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_5;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC,&GPIO_InitStructure);
    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOC, GPIO_Pin_0);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC,&GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN_FLOATING;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_7;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC,&GPIO_InitStructure);

    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BaudRatePrescaler_64;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CPHA = SPI_CPHA_1Edge;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CPOL = SPI_CPOL_Low;
    //SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CRCPolynomial =
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_DataSize = SPI_DataSize_16b;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_Direction = SPI_Direction_2Lines_FullDuplex;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_FirstBit = SPI_FirstBit_MSB;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_Mode = SPI_Mode_Master;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_NSS = SPI_NSS_Soft;
    SPI_Init(SPI1, &SPI_InitStructure);

    SPI_Cmd(SPI1, ENABLE);

}

void TIM1_Init(void){

    NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure = {0};
    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TimeBaseInitStructure = {0};
    TIM_OCInitTypeDef TIM_OCInitStructure = {0};

    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_TIM1, ENABLE);

    TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_ClockDivision = TIM_CKD_DIV1;
    TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
    TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_Period = 240; // 240ms
    TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_Prescaler = PSC_1ms;
    TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_RepetitionCounter = 0;
    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM1, &TimeBaseInitStructure);

    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCIdleState = TIM_OCIdleState_Reset;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCMode = TIM_OCMode_Timing;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCPolarity = TIM_OCPolarity_Low;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OutputState = TIM_OutputState_Disable;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_Pulse = 150;
    TIM_OC1Init(TIM1, &TIM_OCInitStructure);

    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM1_UP_IRQn;
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 1;// Can interrupt an interruption
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0;
    NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM1_CC_IRQn;
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0;// Can interrupt an interruption
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0;
    NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

    //TIM_OC1PreloadConfig(TIM1, TIM_OCPreload_Disable);
    //TIM_ITConfig(TIM1, TIM_IT_Update | TIM_IT_CC1, ENABLE);
    TIM_ITConfig(TIM1, TIM_IT_Update, ENABLE);
    TIM_Cmd(TIM1, ENABLE);
}

void GPIOD_Init(void){

    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure  = {0};

    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOD, ENABLE);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_2;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStructure);
    GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_2);
}

/* Systick_Init : Starts the system timer
 * */
void Systick_Init(void){
    SysTick->SR=0;
    SysTick->CNT=0;
    SysTick->CMP=0x0;
    SysTick->CTLR=0x01;
}

/* Read temperature function
 * */

float read_temperature(void){
    float t_mp = 0.0;
    uint16_t temperature;
    if(SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1, SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE) != RESET){
        GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOC, GPIO_Pin_0);
        SPI_I2S_SendData(SPI1, 0xAA);
        while(SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1, SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE) != SET){};//Waiting TX buffer is empty

        if(SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1, SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE != RESET))
        {
            temperature = SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI1);
            Delay_Ms(5);
            if(temperature & 0x0004){
                t_mp = -1.0;
            }else{
                t_mp = 0.25*(uint16_t)(temperature>>3);
            }
        }
        //read_temp_flag = 0;
        GPIO_SetBits(GPIOC, GPIO_Pin_0);
        return t_mp;
    }else{
        return t_mp;
    }
}

int main(){

    // USART1 : Tx -> D.5
    USART_Printf_Init(115200);
    GPIOD_Init();
    SPI1_Init();
    TIM1_Init();
    printf("Sysclk:%d\r\n",SystemCoreClock);
    while(1){
        if(read_temp_flag != 0){
            //val = read_temperature();

            if(SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1, SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE) != RESET){
                GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOC, GPIO_Pin_0);//CS <- '0'
                SPI_I2S_SendData(SPI1, 0xAA);
                while(SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1, SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE) != SET){};//Waiting TX buffer is empty

                if(SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1, SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE != RESET))
                {
                    temperature = SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI1);
                    Delay_Ms(2);
                    if(temperature & 0x0004){ //If thermocouple input is OPEN
                        val = -1.0;
                    }else{
                        val = 0.25*(uint16_t)(temperature>>3);
                    }
                }
                GPIO_SetBits(GPIOC, GPIO_Pin_0);//CS <- '1'
            }
            float_printf(val);
            read_temp_flag = 0;
        }
    }
}

void float_printf(float n){

    val_int = (int)n;
    printf("%d.%d\r\n",(int)n,(int)(n*100) % 100);

}
```

Comment: What happens when it does not work?

Comment: When I run firmware using the function read_temperature() i got this :running the firmware without delay

Comment: Running the firmware using the function read_temperature() . If there's no delay I got 0.0, with a delay of  5ms I got -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0 and so on, with a delay of 8ms I  got 0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 20.75, 20.50, 21.0, 20.50 (that's or less correct). However, in debug mode without everything works well.

Comment: If I add the code for rotary encoder, I have to increase the delay to 20ms to make it works well. Everything works well in  debugging mode.

Comment: Please do NOT add information in comments, it will not be read. [Edit] your question and add it there, please. -- What tells you "_running the firmware without delay_"? If it is your IDE, it is correct and neither a warning nor an error. It just tells you that the firmware runs at full speed. That would be what I expect normally. ;-)

Comment: Please reduce the amount of source and provide a [mre] that still exhibits the behaviour. And a link to the MAX6675 data sheet would be greatly appreciated.